# How to make sure end date is always 7 days more than start date?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a page that shows the start date and end date like below:

[image]

As you can see the end date is always 7 days more than the start date by default. I am allowed to change the start date but how do I make sure every time I change the start date,the end date also adds up 7 days to the respective start date?

Code:

```
  <%

        String relPath = "../../../";
        String currentDate = CoreUtil.parseDate(new Date());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //get current date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //Number of Days to add
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        String defaultDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());





    %>

Start Date:&emsp;<input class="txtStartDate" style="font: 13px/1.231 Trebuchet MS;" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly><br><br>


End Date: &emsp; <input class="txtEndDate" style="font: 13px/1.231 Trebuchet MS;" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>"  readonly required/>
```

Edit:

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<Script>
    $('#txtStartDate').datepicker();
    $('#txtEndDate').datepicker();

    $('#txtStartDate').change(function(){
        var interval = 7;

        function convertDateString(p) { return (p < 10) ? '0' + p : p; }

        var startDate = new Date($(this).val());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
        $('#txtEndDate').val( startDate.getFullYear() + '/' +     convertDateString(startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + convertDateString(startDate.getDate()));
    });

</script>
```

Basically whenever I change my start date, the end date should be automatically change to (start date+7 days) as well, that's all I'm trying to do. The above code should have work but it did not change my end date when I changed my start date.

Comment: What are you asking? How to detect that Start Date has changed? How to get a date value from it, add 7 days, and get string for End Date, in **JavaScript**? *(Not Java, since this should happen in the web browser, so question is really tagged with the wrong question).*

Comment: I apologize that i phrased it with the wrong tag. I edited my post so it's clearer.

Comment: a good library is momentJS, it could really help you out with that.

Comment: My friend could you please mark my answer as the accepted one if it helped you, okay?

Answer (score 3):

This might help.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

$('#txtStartDate').datepicker();
$('#txtEndDate').datepicker();

$('#txtStartDate').change(function(){
    var interval = 7;
    var startDate = new Date($(this).val());
    $('#txtEndDate').val(startDate.addDays(interval));
});
```

Comment: Daredevil, if that helped you could you please mark this as the accepted answer? It's very important to me...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the calculation using a JavaScript Date object and the formatting using Strings:

```js
// Get references to HTML elements
const startInput = document.getElementById("txtStartDate");
const endInput = document.getElementById("txtEndDate");

// Listen for changes to #txtStartDate
startInput.addEventListener("change", updateEndDate);

// Respond to changes
function updateEndDate(event){

  // Calculate end date
  let endDate = new Date(startInput.value);
  endDate.setUTCDate(endDate.getUTCDate() + 7);

  // Separate the parts of end date
  let yyyy = endDate.getUTCFullYear(),
      mm = endDate.getUTCMonth() + 1,
      dd = endDate.getUTCDate();

  // Add initial zeros if needed
  if(mm < 10){mm = "0" + mm; }
  if(dd < 10){dd = "0" + dd; }

  // Format and display end date
  endInput.value = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="txtStartDate" />
<input type="date" id="txtEndDate" />
```