# Automatically changes end date after start date is picked

Tags: javascript

So I have this scenario with a screen like below:

[image]

I am trying to make the end date always 7 days greater than the start date. So when I change the start date to `2019-05-01`,then end date should be `2019-05-08` and so on and so forth.

I am using datepicker library to make this work.

Code:

```
Start Date:&emsp;<input class="txtStartDate" style="font: 13px/1.231 Trebuchet MS;" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly><br><br>


End Date: &emsp; <input class="txtEndDate" style="font: 13px/1.231 Trebuchet MS;" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>"  readonly required/><br><br>


<script>

$(function() {

  $(".txtEndDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    title: 'Click to open calendar',
    alt: 'Click to open calendar'
  });
});

$(function() {

  $(".txtStartDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    title: 'Click to open calendar',
    alt: 'Click to open calendar'
  });
});

$('#txtStartDate').datepicker();
$('#txtEndDate').datepicker();

$('#txtStartDate').change(function() {
  var interval = 7;

  function convertDateString(p) {
    return (p < 10) ? '0' + p : p;
  }

  var startDate = new Date($(this).val());
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
  $('#txtEndDate').val(startDate.getFullYear() + '/' + convertDateString(startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + convertDateString(startDate.getDate()));
});

</script>
```

I implemented an onchange function to get it to work but there's no changes to it, is there anything I did wrong?

Screenshot of my datepicker:

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using? This looks almost like jQuery UI Datepicker, but it doesn't have `title` and `alt`.

Comment: It's redirects me to `jquery-ui-1.82.custom.min.js` , is that correct?

Comment: can you log `startDate` before set last line set value.

Comment: @Kaushik I don't follow what you're saying.

Comment: I edited my post to include a screenshot of the datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure end date is always 7 days more than start date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803646/how-to-make-sure-end-date-is-always-7-days-more-than-start-date)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your prior question. Four questions in two hours on the same theme is quite excessive anyway - it is worth being careful that your enthusiasm for asking questions does not turn into help vampirism.

Comment: But they are not duplicate, is that not allowed? Otherwise, i will delete it

Comment: It is technically OK if they are not duplicates (and since you now have some answers, it would be unfair on helpers to delete it). Nevertheless, I am still of the view that if you are asking four questions in two hours, you are not doing enough research on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, rather than listening to `$('#[start/end datepicker id]').change` you can use the provided `.on("change", function()`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzboqacd/2/) or snippet below:

```js
var interval = 7;
    $(function() {
      $("#sdatepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: interval
      });

      $("#edatepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
      });

      var today = new Date();
      var target = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + interval);
      $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("setDate", today);
      $("#edatepicker").datepicker("setDate", target);

      $("#sdatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        title: 'Click to open calendar',
        alt: 'Click to open calendar'
      }).on("change", function() {
        var start = $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("getDate");
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);
        $("#edatepicker").datepicker("setDate", start);
        $("#edatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate",
          $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
      });

      $("#edatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        title: 'Click to open calendar',
        alt: 'Click to open calendar'
      }).on("change", function() {
        var start = $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("getDate");
        $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("setDate", start);
        $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate",
          $("#edatepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
      });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="sdatepicker"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="edatepicker"></p>
```

Explanation:

`minDate` is used to prevent past date to be selected. 0 is today.

Using interval you can update the start/end date with a fixed interval when any of them was changed, and to limit end date cannot be less than the start date
and start date cannot be greater than the end date you can combine `maxDate` and `minDate`:

```
$("#edatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#sdatepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
```

and:

```
$("#sdatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", $("#edatepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
```

### Update

The following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe1tg4z7/) solved OP problem apparently as [discussed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/192245). Snippet:

```js
var interval = 7;
$(function() {
  var start;
  var today = new Date();
  var target = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + interval);
  $(".txtStartDate").datepicker("setDate", today);
  $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", target);

  $(".txtStartDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    title: 'Click to open calendar',
    alt: 'Click to open calendar',
    onSelect: function() {
      start = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);
      $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
      $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",
        $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
    $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",
      $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
  });

  $(".txtEndDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    title: 'Click to open calendar',
    alt: 'Click to open calendar'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Start Date: <input type="text" class="txtStartDate"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" class="txtEndDate"></p>
```

`$(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option","minDate", start.getDate())`

won't work because

`var start = $(".txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");` is initialized, then updated into `start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);`.

Which mean `start.getDate()` won't result in `$(".txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");`

While `$(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", 
$(".txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate"));` work.

Also, apparently previous month won't trigger `onchange` or `onselect` setting the end date while calling them twice and early initializing of `var start;` would:

```
onSelect: function() {
      start = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);
      $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
      $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",
        $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
    $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",
      $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent people from choosing the end date < start date? because it doesn't make sense

Comment: There is, like in my example. The end date can't be picked less than today + interval. To prevent past date being picked you can modify the `minDate` value.

Comment: i followed the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804334/javascript-setting-mindate-to-prevent-from-choosing-date-before-current-date/55804372?noredirect=1#comment98276691_55804372

Comment: Perhaps can that be changed to make sure end date cannot be chosen less than start date?

Comment: i tested your fiddle, it doesn't let me choose any date for end date after 30th

Comment: Do you mean before? Since `minDate` only restrict past date set not future date.

Comment: But for end date, i cannot choose 26th april, it's blurred out

Comment: That's because I set `minDate: interval` which is today+7. If you don't need it, it could be removed. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/3zy0den8/

Comment: I get what you mean now, but i'm trying to prevent people from selecting end date <start date or start date>end date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192245/discussion-between-shinjo-and-daredevil).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `change` event of the input. Use the datepicker's `onSelect` option, it runs a callback when you select a date from it.

And you should use the `setDate()` method of the other datepicker to change its date.

```js
  $(".txtStartDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    title: 'Click to open calendar',
    alt: 'Click to open calendar',
    onSelect: function(value, dp) {
      var interval = 7;
      var start = dp.datepicker("getDate");
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);
      $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't follow, so how should the end date datepicker be?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `$(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);` changes the end date datepicker.

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to the end datepicker, just this change to the start datepicker.

Comment: I see. I am not too familiar with this library, is there a way to prevent user to choose start date/end date that are before today? E.g 2019-03-01. I thought maybe i can add something to the function above.

Comment: Use the `minDate` option. Why don't you read the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/