# Setting minDate to prevent from choosing enddate before start date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a start date and end date for me to choose the date. I am using jQuery datepicker library.

This is how my function looks like for now:

```
$(function() {

        $(".txtEndDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            title:'Click to open calendar',
            alt:'Click to open calendar'
        });


    });




    $(function() {

        $(".txtStartDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,

            title:'Click to open calendar',
            alt:'Click to open calendar',

            onSelect: function() {
                var start = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                start.setDate(start.getDate() + 7);
                $(".txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", start);
            }

        });



    });
```

It works but I want to make it when users are not allowed to choose a date before today because it doesn't make sense anyway.For example,choosing `2018-01-01` is not supposed to be valid. You get the idea.

Found a documentation that suggests using `minDate` to solve this.It says:

```
//initialize the datepicker
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});

//get or set mindate option
// Getter
var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

Seeing as I am confused on what the fields represent, is there a way I could prevent people from selecting any dates before today?

I tried this solution:
[jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

But it doesn't disable it and still allows me to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable past dates using minDate property of datepicker plugin, as below.

```js
$(".txtEndDate").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),  // Add this to diсable past date
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '../../../images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            title:'Click to open calendar',
            alt:'Click to open calendar'
        });
```

Comment: new Date(), will take default format of local system

Comment: so add this to both txtenddate and txtstartdate?

Comment: Yes, you can add this to both txtendate and txtstartdate datepickers

Comment: what will happen if i try to select previous dates before today?

Comment: adding this will disable the previous date before today, it'll not allow you to select past dates

Comment: is there a way to prevent people from choosing end date< start date? it doesn't make sense

Comment: You can write code on change event of both the datepicker and validate your date end date<start date or whatever validation you want

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192246/discussion-between-abhishek-and-daredevil).

Answer (score 1):

use the below code it will help you to prevent selecting old date from today.

```
minDate : 0 // for current date

minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) // for particular minDate
```

```js
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 0  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input class="DateFrom">
```

code to end date less that start date please refer the code :-

```
  $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#EndDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#EndDate").datepicker({ 
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#StartDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });
```

Comment: why it is 0? and not current date

Comment: @Daredevil 0 refers the current date, you can also change the date to fixed date like this  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)

Comment: is there a way to prevent people from choosing end date< start date? it doesn't make sense

Comment: @Daredevil sure you can use maxDate: "+1m +1w"  like this. to set end date.but its use less to set end date < start date.

Comment: I don't follow, how do i make sure i cannot choose end date that is less than start date?

Comment: @Daredevil check my code i have updated the code which you want.

Comment: So when I choose start date, the start date cannot be greater than end date. And when i choose end date, the end date cannot be less than start date. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: @Daredevil yes that is what it mean.

Comment: Can you post the code in respect to mine? Because your answer changes some variable and i don't understand it

Comment: @Daredevil okay tell me what u exactly want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192247/discussion-between-daredevil-and-bathri-nathan).